# ST3: Simple dummy plugin that takes and input from user and print in at the cursor

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I'm trying to write a simple dummy Sublime Text 3 plugin that will take an input (show_input_panel) and prints into the buffer.

I have come with this:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class DummyCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):

        def on_done(text):
            self.view.insert(edit, 0, text)

        view = sublime.active_window().show_input_panel("Write Something", "", on_done, None, None)
```

However, there is problem with edit:

```
>>> view.run_command("dummy")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/libor/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Tools/dummy.py", line 8, in on_done
    self.view.insert(edit, 0, text)
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime.py", line 645, in insert
    raise ValueError("Edit objects may not be used after the TextCommand's run method has returned")
ValueError: Edit objects may not be used after the TextCommand's run method has returned
```

Answer (score 2):

The command has returned after the show_input_panel has completed (thus closing the edit object). You should be able to use `self.view.run_command("insert", {"characters": text})` in your callback to get the effect you want.